# system interrupts using 25% cpu?

Tags: windows-7

System interrupts seems to be jumping to 25% cpu and then back down when I'm running OBS and have my Blue Yeti Pro plugged in.

Not sure as to why this is happening, and I can't find any information as why it is happening. A lot of different information on the system interrupts issue, but not with a Blue Yeti that i can find.

It doesn't do it when the Blue Yeti isn't plugged in and OBS is running, and it doesn't happen when the Blue Yeti is plugged in without OBS running.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rXol.png]

Comment: too long to answer here, [go to this link and do some reading](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/140263-how-to-get-the-cause-of-high-cpu-usage-by-dpc-interrupt/)

Comment: if latencyMon doesn't help, run the xperf command that I posted in my msfn guide.

Answer (score 2):

Neither you nor I have any idea what is going on with the DPCs.

Want to find out?

First, we're going to download Resplendence's [LatencyMon](http://www.resplendence.com/downloads) as instructed in [this forum post](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/140263-how-to-get-the-cause-of-high-cpu-usage-by-dpc-interrupt/) (thanks to Moab). You can choose to run the installer or use something like [InnoUnp](http://innounp.sourceforge.net/) to extract the files yourself from the installer.

Once you have the executables, run `LatMon.exe`. You'll need admin permission as some kernel drivers will be installed on startup. Click `Start Monitor` on the top left.

You should see something like this:

[image: Latency Monitor]

The `Highest reported DPC routine execution time` is what you're looking for. Note the driver's name to the right of it, and continue to the `Drivers` tab.

On the drivers tab, you could look at this a few different ways by sorting by `Total execution` or `DPC count`. Regardless, you should get what you're looking for:

[image: Drivers list]

The culprit driver should be very apparent on your end. (The culprit doesn't look very apparent on my end, however, and that's because there is no culprit. Everything's well balanced.)

Be sure to post back with the culprit driver's name and to update whatever it belongs to.